# Resolve the view path for a controller in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, rendering

I want a shared js response (view) that I render from a bunch of controllers.  It lives in `app/views/shared/success.js.erb`.

This is a standard response for *most* of my controllers, that modifies the DOM with some content.  This content however is particular to the controller that is rendering it.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to resolve the view path for a particular controller from this shared js view.  He's an example (includes some namespaced controllers)

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    # do some stuff
    render 'shared/success' # .js.erb
  end
end

# app/controllers/settings/permissions_controller
class Settings::PermissionsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    # do some stuff
    render 'shared/success' # .js.erb
  end
end

# app/views/users/success.html.erb
<p>Some View code that only relates to <strong>users</strong></p>

# app/views/settings/permissions/success.html.erb
<p>Some View code that only relates to <strong>permission settings</strong></p>

# app/views/shared/success.js.erb
var listItem = '<%= j render "#{insert resolved path to this particular controller instance}/success.html.erb" %>'
$(".list").append(listItem);
```

The reason I want to do this is because the js response is always the same, it's just the content that changes.  Any thoughts on how I can get the current controller's default view rendering path?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current action name using:

```
params[:action]
```

Then you can customize the view accordingly.

Alternatively, you can just set an instance variable in these controllers with value you expect in the .js view, and just use it in the view.